# Self sizing TableView cell with image and label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

hello I have a dynamic TableViewController in which there is one cell which has one image, and labels. I have set constraint of all of them. The problem is its not viewing correctly.

[image]

This is how its viewing

[image]

Code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 103

            }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.setNeedsLayout()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.reloadData()





    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return newarray.count
           }

    override
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("requestcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewRequestTableViewCell

       let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder_product_image")!
        cell.imageView!.image = image
        cell.requestTitle.text = "IPHONE 6s PLUS"
        cell.DestinationCountry.text = "Pakistan"

        return cell

    }
```

I don't know what else to do. Please help how can I have row like I designed

Comment: Override `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the height of your cell
add the following methods in your code: (replacing of course  <#cell_height#> by the value of your choice, or by UITableViewAutomaticDimension)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return <#cell_height#>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for tableView self sizing to work, you need to add constraint to both top and bottom of UILabel.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 103
```

I think your trying is right, but you need to increase the estimatedRowHeight. i.e, 300 or 600.

And you need to add constraints on Storyboard suitably. 
so just add up, left, right, bottom distance constraints.
Never give the width & height constraints there.

Beside you need to call the cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded just in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

I think it will work then.

Sincerely, 
Harri.